# Make table with returned values in jQuery takes 10x more time than call api in server

Tags: python, api, flask, request, themoviedb-api

I'm trying to return results from themoviedb.com API. I measured that the whole python function takes 0.3s, but javascript makes table after 3-5s, how is it possible?

API call function in flask

```
def whispererSeries(partOfName):
    # ODESLANI REQUEST NA API PRO ODPOVIDAJICI SERIALY
    # API CALL
    url = URL('https://api.themoviedb.org/3/search/tv?api_key=' + config['API_KEY'] + '&language=en-US&query=' + str(
        partOfName) + '&page=1')
    http = HTTPClient(url.host)
    response = http.get(url.request_uri)
    body = json.loads(response.read().decode('utf-8'))

    if response.status_code == 200:

        # VRACEJICI SE HODNOTA
        # RETURN ARRAY OF DICTIONARIES
        valToReturn = []

        if (len(body['results']) > config['FIND_MAX_RESULTS']):

            for i in range(config['FIND_MAX_RESULTS']):
                valToReturn.append({
                    'Name': body['results'][i]['name'],
                    'Url': getUrlOfSerie(str(body['results'][i]['id']))
                })

        elif (len(body['results']) > 0):
            for i in range(len(body['results'])):
                valToReturn.append(body['results'][i]['name'])

        else:
            valToReturn = []
        return jsonify(valToReturn)

    else:
        print('Error: %r') % (response.status_code)
```

And here in jQuery i call python function and append returned values to table.

```
// ODELSANI POZADAVKU NA SERVER
// CALL SERVER FUNCTION
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        contentType: 'application/json;charset=UTF-8',
        // ODESLANI HODNOTY INPUTU
        data: JSON.stringify($('.find-input').val()),

        // CILOVA ADRESA
        // ROUTE
        url: '/indexWhisperer',
        success: (response)=> {
            console.log(response)
            // VYCISTENI OD PREDCHOZICH VYSLEDKU
            // CLEAR FROM PREVIOUS RESULTS
            $('.founded-results tbody').empty()

            // NASTAVENI VIDITELNOSTI TABULKY A PRIDANI VYSLEDKU
            // MAKE TABLE VISIBLE AND APPEND RESULTS
            response.forEach((item, index, array)=>{
                $('.founded-results').css({'visibility': 'visible'})
                $('.founded-results tbody').append('<tr><td><a href="' + item.Url + '">' + item.Name + '<a/></td></tr>');
            })
        },
        error: (error)=>{
            throw error
        }
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

Just had made a MySQL database, inserted data from api and now it's a lot of faster.